# Local CA for remote web server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, web-server, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority

I have two domains and the one I am in has a certificate authority server.  The domain I am not in doesn't have a CA server.  I want to certify https on that server so that I can get there without the cert warnings.

What I did:
Created a CSR on the web server and generated a certificate on the CA.  I then completed the CSR on the web server.  I also exported the intermediate certificate and imported that into the web server.

I'm still getting the cert warnings.  Is there something I did wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the root CA's certificate installed in your Trusted Root CAs certificate store?  Your client must trust the CA before it will trust certificates issued by that CA.

Comment: Yes.  All of our clients have the local CA server certificate installed in Trusted Root CA's.